# Order confirmation email {{payment_html}} block

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to edit some of Magento's transactional emails (the order confirmation ones). My aim is to change the order of the order totals so that "Tax" comes before "Subtotal" (our subtotal already includes tax). I've found that the totals are generated in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\sales\order\totals.phtml` via [this loop](http://paste2.org/p/2590320).

There is a condition which states:

```
<?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
    <strong><?php echo $_total->getLabel()?></strong>
<?php else:?>
    <?php echo $_total->getLabel()?>
<?php endif?>
```

My main questions are:

1. What is `->getStrong()` doing, and where is it defined, because I can't find it anywhere even after using grep to search the codebase.
2. Are the labels (such as "Subtotal", "Tax", "Grand Total", etc.) stored anywhere in Magento's back end?
3. Any ideas on how I'd go about changing the order of the fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look @

1) Take a look /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

```
$this->_totals['grand_total'] = new Varien_Object(array(
    ..
    'strong'=> true,
    'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
    'label' => $this->__('Grand Total')
));
```

2) app/locale/en_US/Mage_Sales.csv

see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/29444/

3) Admin -> System -> Config -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Any ideas about getStrong() though?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks so much. I'll accept the answer, but my only last query is "how is getStrong() implemented?" I can't find a "getStrong" function defined anywhere. Is it some kind of magic getter/setter functionality?

Comment: 'strong'=> true = getStrong()

Comment: I know, but is there some PHP magic in the call of "getStrong"? That is, if I define a new property within the Varien_Object, let's say "banana", can I call "getBanana()" and it'll get its value?

Comment: Yes, once it is a Varien object e.g `$x = new Varien_Object(array('banana' => 'yes')); echo $x->getBanana() //yes`